# Bug in Android App - Nav Drawer

Tags: bug, android-app

The notifications navigation drawer on the right seems to close automatically when it detects a scroll down.

[image]

Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with 5.0 Android.

The app version is: Version 1.0.89

Comment: **Not** reproducible on Motorola XT1033, OS 5.1 (2), App version 1.0.89